# Consider the Itô process $\{X_t,t\ge0\}$ to calculate the probability that $X_t$ is a least $5\%$ higher than $X_0$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning, brownian-motion

> Consider the Itô process $\{X_t,t\ge0\}$ described by the stochastic
> differential equation $$dX_t = 0.10X_t dB_t + 0.25X_t dt.$$ Calculate
> the probability that $X_t$ is at least $5\%$ higher than $X_0$
>
> - at time $t = 0.01$, and
> - at time $t = 1$.
>
> Source: [University of Regina, Fall 2014, 441 (assignment #4) pg. 1](https://uregina.ca/%7Ekozdron/Teaching/Regina/441Fall14/Assign/assign04.pdf)

### My Work So Far

We note the price of the stock follows a Brownian motion given by
$$dX_t=0.25X_tdt+0.10X_tdB_t,$$
therefore we can calculate
\begin{align*}
X_t&=X_0e^{0.10B_t+(0.25-\frac{0.10^2}{2})t}\\
&=X_0e^{0.19B_t+0.245t}\\
\end{align*}
If $Z\sim N(0,1)$, then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X_t\gt1.05X_0)&=\mathbb{P}\left(B_t \geq\frac{\log(1.05)-0.245t}{0.10}\right)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(Z\ge\frac{\log(1.05)-0.245t}{0.10\sqrt{t}}\right)\\
\end{align*}
We can conclude with

- if $t=0.01$, then
  \begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}(X_{0.01}\geq1.05X_0)&=\mathbb{P}\left(Z\ge\frac{\log(1.05)-0.245(0.01)}{0.10\sqrt{0.01}}\right)\\
  &=\mathbb{P}(Z\geq4.634)\\
  &=1-\Phi(4.634)\\
  &\approx0.000002.\\
  \end{align*}

```
1-pnorm(4.634)
[1] 1.793335e-06
```

- if $t=1$, then
  \begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}(X_{1}\geq1.05X_0)&=\mathbb{P}\left(Z\ge\frac{\log(1.05)-0.245(1)}{0.10\sqrt{1}}\right)\\
  &=\mathbb{P}(Z\geq-1.962)\\
  &=\Phi(1.962)\\
  &\approx0.9751.\\
  \end{align*}

```
pnorm(1.962)
[1] 0.9751188
```

Would this be correct? Is there a better way to calculus this?

Comment: +1. Sounds like you did everything correctly.